# Javascript: function called once, but is executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work on a script, that makes ajax request to pull more feeds from the server. Somewhat like pagination.

The problem here is `SiteHelper.loadMoreFeeds()` function is called once when a "More" link is clicked. But the function's code executes twice. Can't figure out why this is happening. 
There's no loop nor recursive calls.

I've tried "alerting" in some points, to verify that function is called only once; which is true but it's code is executed twice.

Thanks in advance

```
//SiteHelper = {....}  has lots of code already

SiteHelper.loadMoreFeeds = function (loaderUri, limit) {
    $(".feeds-loadmore .more").hide();
    $('.feeds-loadmore').find('.loading-anim').fadeIn();

    alert('loadMoreFeeds called');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: SiteHelper.baseUrl(loaderUri),
        data: { 'limit': limit },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('.feeds-loadmore').remove();
            $("#content").append('<!-- [data] : ' + JSON.stringify(limit) + ' -->');
            $("#content").append(result);
            $("#content").append('<!-- //[data] -->');
            alert('ajax success');
        }
    });
};


$(function() {
    $('#content').on('click', '.feeds-loadmore a.more', function(e) {
        var loaderUri = decodeURIComponent( $(this).attr('data-loader') );
        var limitData = $(this).attr('data-limit');

        if(!loaderUri)
            return;

        alert('clicked');

        SiteHelper.loadMoreFeeds( loaderUri, JSON.parse(limitData) ); 

        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

Comment: Is your JS file containing this code being loaded twice? Check your HTML source.

Comment: You are using a delegated event handler for the click. Are you accidentally nesting the `.feeds-loadmore a.more` class inside your `.feeds-loadmore a.more` class during load? (check the DOM). That would result in multiple calls. (2 then 3 then 4 etc)

Comment: NO its included once. the function is called only once. That alert('clicked'); is executed once. But the alert('loadMoreFeeds called'); and eventually alert('ajax success'); are executed 2 times

Comment: How are you verifying that it is executing twice? Your comment about the `alert`s suggests that it isn't. If you're seeing duplicate content in `#content`, could the request to `SiteHelper.baseUrl(loaderUri)` be responding with what was already being displayed again?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: no, I checked the DOM. there's only one `.feeds-loadmore a.more`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski SiteHelper.baseUrl(loaderUri) just returns the url for the controller. Yes, problem is I'm getting two alerts "loadMoreFeeds called" for one click on the link and same content getting appended twice. But the "clicked" alert is being shown only once

Comment: As a test, can you add `:first` to the click filter e.g. `.feeds-loadmore a.more:first`? or even `.feeds-loadmore:first a.more:first` (just to be sure)

Comment: I've once had this problem when working with BonFire for CodeIgniter. The problem was that the caching routine didn't remove old js files when caching the new ones. Could it be something like that? If not, try using console.log('fire!')'s in every spot that could trigger the function. That helps tracing down the problem, sometimes.

Comment: @kabirbaidhya did you solve this?

Comment: Apparently, yes. But it was long time back so I totally forgot what I did here.